# Convert negative data into positive data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The current data of the table is:

```
  a   b
---------
 -1   5
-11   2
 -5  32
```

My request is to convert every data into a positive value.

Unfortunately, I forgot the name of the built-in function of SQL Server that enables to convert.

Comment: Don't mind them. Good question and good answers provided!

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You are thinking in the function `ABS`, that gives you the absolute value of numeric data.

```
SELECT ABS(a) AS AbsoluteA, ABS(b) AS AbsoluteB
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 28):

**The best solution is:** from positive to negative or from negative to positive

For negative:

```
SELECT ABS(a) * -1 AS AbsoluteA, ABS(b) * -1 AS AbsoluteB
FROM YourTable
```

For positive:

```
SELECT ABS(a) AS AbsoluteA, ABS(b)  AS AbsoluteB
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: The best solutions come from reading the question carefully. The OP wanted everything +ve not everything inverted.

Comment: Agree but i came here to find the positive to negative, and this solution came into my mind and i posted it. and if you notice i mentioned in answer positive to negative and negative to positive. May be helpful for some one else.

Answer (score 10):

```
UPDATE mytbl
SET a = ABS(a)
where a < 0
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the absolute value function [ABS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx).  The syntax is

```
ABS ( numeric_expression )
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy and straightforward solution using the **CASE** function:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ( a > 0 ) THEN (a*-1) ELSE (a*-1) END AS NegativeA,
       CASE WHEN ( b > 0 ) THEN (b*-1) ELSE (b*-1) END AS PositiveB
FROM YourTableName
```

Answer (score 1):

Update all negatives to positive

```sql
UPDATE my_table 
SET value = ABS(value)
WHERE value < 0
```

Get all the negative

```sql
SELECT value FROM my_table 
WHERE value < 0
```

Get all the negatives and convert them to positive

```sql
SELECT ABS(value) FROM my_table 
WHERE value < 0
```

Comment: What does this answer add to the question? The `update` is already shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9773949/16019058), and the `select` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9773922/16019058)